# Installing on an acer aspire laptop

Tags: boot

I'm trying to get my laptop running ubuntu 16, I know these things are notoriously annoying to get to boot, I must have read a hundred posts about bios settings by now.

I installed from a usb stick and it all went smoothly. I added grub and the other efi files to secure boot mode, and in uefi mode it gives the blue error box that says default boot device missing or boot failed. With secure boot off it gives the same thing and the boot options menu is always just 1. Yes. Legacy mode gives me PXE-MOF exiting no Bootable device.

In this mode with these settings i can run the liveusb but i guess it's defaulting to that since it can't find the hdd for some reason. Can somebody please explain what's going wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: The computer isn't detecting your EFI partition. I recommend startup repair or a reinstallation. Don't play with the efi files/grub and disable secure boot when you reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Set the boot mode to UEFI and turn off secure boot.
Set the SAT operation to AHCI more.
TO make the bootable device(pendrive) use Rufus in "GTP partition scheme for UEFI computer" mode.
Install the OS and run "Boot Repair" on the live mode without restarting.